# Does OSRM acutally provide pubic http API for bikes?

Tags: osrm

I want to use [OSRM http api](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/?language=cURL#route-service). In particular, I want to use the "route" service, with the "bike" profile.

However, when requesting https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/bike/48.4292,-3.8013;48.2539,-2.9004, I get a "Not found" response.

I tried the same request, with "driving" profile. I does work. https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/48.4292,-3.8013;48.2539,-2.9004

I can't find what is wrong in my request. I'm wondering if OSRM actually provides a http service for the "bike" profile.

Comment: An update on this question (which is also my question about OSRM): the links above both work, but the results (e.g. duration, distance) of 'driving' and 'bike' are the same as the mode of 'foot'. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the the front-facing OSRM instance only has "car" implemented:

https://github.com/ropensci/stplanr/issues/246#issuecomment-378281881

Comment: Hum, too bad...Thanks for your answer.